# How to compute integrals dependent upon two variables with SciPy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How to compute integrals of this kind with SciPy?

Product of functions P1 and P2 depends of *x* and integration variable *du*

It would be nice to express result as lambda function, like:

joint_p = lambda x: quad(*[some code here]*, ...

[image]

Comment: Looks like an integral over `u`, with an extra argument `x`.  Write a function.  A `lambda`, if possible will be too messy.  It may require 2 functions and integrations.

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382952/python-fsolve-with-unknown-inside-the-upper-limit-of-an-integral/27384969#27384969.  See the definition of `func` (you don't need the code that uses `fsolve`).

Comment: Have you had a chance to check whether my solution works for you?

Comment: yep, thanks Andras, works like charm, I had not idea how to pass two variables inside integrand function, so "lambda u,x=x" solved it totally, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason why a straightforward use of `scipy.integrate.quad` won't work? I mean:

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.integrate

#define some dummy p1 and p2
def p1(y):
    return 3*y+2
def p2(y):
    return -4*y-4

#define p_{xi1+xi2}
def pplus(x):
    return sp.integrate.quad(lambda u,x=x: p1(u)*p2(x-u), 0, x)[0]
#define p_{xi1/xi2}
def pdivide(x):
    return sp.integrate.quad(lambda u,x=x: u*p1(u)*p2(u/x), 0, sp.minimum(x,1))[0]/x**2

#use it
x = 0.2
outplus = pplus(x)
outdivide = pdivide(x)
```

This will result in

```
print(outplus, outdivide)
-2.016 -8.06666666667
```

You might want to define a proper function instead of the latter `lambda`s, in order to catch the full output of `quad` to check if everything went OK with the integration.

---

Let's check with `sympy`:

```
import sympy as sym

U,X = sym.symbols('U,X')
pplus_sym = sym.lambdify(X, sym.integrate((3*U+2)*(-4*(X-U)-4), (U,0,X)))
dct = {'Min': sp.minimum}; #it's best if we tell lambdify what to use for Min
pdivide_sym = sym.lambdify(X, sym.integrate(U*(3*U+2)*(-4*(U/X)-4), (U,0,sym.Min(X,1)))/(X**2), dct)
```

Then the result is

```
print(pplus_sym(x), pdivide_sym(x))
-2.016 -8.06666666667
```